# Find MinArg in Python -- Pandas DFs Distance

Tags: python, pandas

Being new to Python I am wondering the best way to go about determining for every record in DF1, the row in DF2 corresponding to a minimum of the value of a function with parameters involving both DF.

In DF1 are a few hundred thousand records with columns lat1 and lon1 and there are 50,000 records in DF2 with columns lat2, lon2 and zip. I want to apply a function f(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) which calculates the distance between two points (defined using lat1, lon1, lat2,lon2). I ultimately want to add zip from DF2 into Df1 corresponding to the record in D2 corresponding to the smallest distance between that row in Df1 and all rows in D2.

Comment: For all 110k+ records in `df1` do you want to apply your distance function for every record in `df2` ?

Comment: Yes, for each record in DF1 I want to find the record in DF2 where the distance is smallest. There is no constraint that only one record in DF2 can be matched to a single record in DF1. There is just a lookup to say which record in DF2 is closest to each record in DF1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to do 5 billion computations you going to want it to be fast.  I generated 2 random datasets: df1 with a latitude and longitude column and df2 with a longitude, latitude, and zip column.  df1 has 10,000 rows and df2 has 50,000.  For 10,000 rows in df1, this took about 18 secs to run (I have 8 cores) or 0.001805 per record in df1. So you are looking at about 3 mins (or a little worse) for 100,000.

```
%%file lat_long.py

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

###############  Generate random data  ##################
d1 = np.random.randn(20000).reshape((10000, 2))
d2 = np.random.randn(50000*3).reshape((50000, 3))

global df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1, columns = ['lat1', 'lon1'])
global df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns = ['lat2', 'lon2', 'zip'])
#########################################################

def min_gen(a1, a2, n):
    A = a1.lat1[n] - a2.lat2
    A = A*A
    B = a1.lon1[n] - a2.lon2
    B = B*B
    C = np.sqrt(A + B)
    tmp = np.arange(50000).reshape((50000,1))
    D = np.c_[C, tmp]
    return D

def main(i):
    min_arr = min_gen(df1, df2, i)
    return i, min(min_arr[:,0]), min_arr[:,0].argmin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()
    r = p.map(main, range(len(df1)))
    print r

# <next cell>
%%bash 
lat_long.py
```

This program will loop through in parallel and calculate the distances and the min of those distances.  `print r` will print a list of tuples that contain the row # from df1, the minimum distance, and the row # from df2 corresponding to the min (so you can find the zip code).  I'll leave it to you to collect the zip codes and arrange the dataset.

Comment: Thats great! Thank you and i learned multiple things from from this. The fact you are a Brewers fan (live in Michigan...Tigers fan here) shouldn't taint my appreciation :)

Comment: When I run the code as is, I get an error that main requires no arguments. I changed the function name to main_ and the code runs, but doesnt appear to finish - and I dont see any evidence in my memory monitor (windows) that there is any parallel processing occurring. I'm running Python 2.7 in iPython notebook.

Comment: If you are in an IPython notebook, put the entire code in one cell and put `%%file` on the first line as I have and then whatever you want the name of the file to be.  Then run the cell.  Then in the next cell run the program with `%%bash name_of_file.py`

Comment: I am not familiar with this - what does it do? Is this something needed for the parallel processing?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed you said Windows there so `bash` won't work.  It is just a way to run a python script from a notebook w/o have to pull up a terminal.  I'm not very familiar with Windows but if you save the code with a `.py` extension and run `C:/wherever_the_file_is > python lat_long.py` it will execute

Comment: When I run in spyder (w/o the %% bit) it runs fast! very cool. For others to use, you just have one small typo in the definition of columns for df2 (lat2 is repeated). Am curious about iPython though, I am not familiar with needing to do anything special to run code in that tool.

Comment: Here is some info about [IPython](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb) magic

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work,
the list comprehensions below iterate through every item in the second frame for each row in the first. The value and index are stored in a tuple. The minimum of these is found using a lambda that selects the first element. The indices are then extracted by mapping a different lambda which selects the second element only. This is a good explanation of lambdas. http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk.

```
ldf1 = len(list(df1.iterrows()))
ldf2 = len(list(df2.iterrows()))
funk = lambda df1, df2, j, i:f(df1.loc[j, 'lat'], df1.loc[j, 'lon'],df2.loc[i,'lat'], df2.loc[i, 'lon'])
pairs = [min([(funk(DF1, DF2, j, i), i) for i in xrange(ldf2)], key=lambda x:x[0]) for j in xrange(ldf1)]
mins = map(lambda x:x[1], pairs)
```

It's also worth noting that this is going to run in polynomial time, which is going to take a while with the number of rows you have. I chose to use map and list comprehensions because they will be faster than a standard `for each`

Comment: given the amount of data i dont think this is feasible

Comment: I don't see a way for him to accomplish this below polynomial time. Python can certainly handle this many calculations and since there seems to be no limit on time I think it should be ok. However I took this into account and used map, and nested comprehensions which are going to be faster than a for loop. https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops